# Accessing a C++ application from a webpage

Tags: visual-c++, embed

I have created an interactive application in Visual C++ that has a graphical user interface and text output. The code is compiled and runs successfully on my computer.
I would like to make the application available for users to access and run via a website (and maybe email the results text). What do I need to do to achieve that?

Edit: I know that this question may look unresearched for many of you. The application I refer is a real scientific application. The question appears vague because I don't know where exactly to start. I did some browsing, but most was above my experience level. I am still looking, but I couldn't find a route yet.